# Create a message loop and window controls when sending "create" message in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am attempting to port a large Windows app to OS X.

In Windows, I can create a message loop and create the window controls when Windows sends the application the "create" message.  How do I do this in Cocoa?  I'm not using nib files.

Answer (score 1):

Your application delegate's [`applicationDidFinishLaunching:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW3) method is the entry point for a GUI app, and an event loop ("run loop" in Cocoa) will have been created already.

You can set up your interface at that point.

Comment: This is my 1000th answer on SO.